# GeoCoordinateWatcher from Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, geolocation

I am using GeoCoordinateWatcher from a WinForms application in C# to retrieve the geolocation where that app is running, and it works well.

However, some people connect by VPN to a remote desktop and run the WinForms application on the remote desktop, and then it returns the geolocation of the machine where the connect to.

Is there a way so the WinForms application that is running on a remote desktop connection can get the geolocation of the computer that connects to the remote desktop server ?
Or is there a way the WinForms application can know what computer has started the application, not the server but the computer that connected to the remote desktop server and started the application there.

In the application I use GeoCoordinateWatcher like this

```
 this.watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
 this.watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
 bool started = this.watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));


 void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
 {
     if (CurrentLocationChanged != null)
     {
         _latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
         _longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;

         try
         {
             watcher.Stop();
             watcher.Dispose();
         }
         catch { }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is the user "cooperative"? Meaning: is it an option to have the app started with an argument?

Comment: @Fildor Not sure, on the remote desktop (and also on the local computers) there is a shortcut that points to a clickonce application. So I don't think an argument can help me much here

Comment: [Harvesting ClickOnce Command Line Arguments](http://briannoyes.net/harvesting-clickonce-command-line-arguments/) (on-line) -- [How to pass arguments to an offline ClickOnce application](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/) (off-line, not necessarily applicable)